# Akka HTTP: Create HTTPResponse from Abstract Type

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-http

we are using akka-http and needs to return multiple responses on the basis of logic. Thats why, in our application we have response hierrarchy like that:

```
object CustomHttpResponse extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val formatter = new RootJsonWriter[CustomHttpResponse] {
        override def write(obj : CustomHttpResponse) : JsValue = obj match
        {
            case success : Success =>
                JsObject("type" -> "success".toJson, "value" -> success.toJson)
            case failure : Failure =>
                JsObject("type" -> "failure".toJson, "value" -> failure.toJson)
        }
    }
}

sealed trait CustomHttpResponse {
    def status : Boolean
}

object Success extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val Formatter : RootJsonFormat[Success] = jsonFormat1(Success.apply)
}
case class Success(override val status : Boolean) extends CustomHttpResponse

object Failure extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val Formatter : RootJsonFormat[Failure] = jsonFormat3(Failure.apply)
}
case class Failure(override val status : Boolean, cause : String) extends CustomHttpResponse
```

These response are generated on the basis of my conditions and generate by my controller helper method like this:

```
def generateResponse(param1: String, param2: String): HttpResponse[CustomHttpResponse] = { .... }
```

The body of `HttpResponse` class is custom like:

```
case class HttpResponse[T <: CustomHttpResponse](statusCode : Int, body : T)
```

The HttpResponse class is just a kind of DTO, which actually get the values from controller helper and return to controller. In the controller we are trying to fetch the values from controller helper method and set it into akka http `complele(.. )` method like this:

```
val response = generateResponse("data", "data2")
complete(response.statusCode, response.body)
```

While passing the body to complete method, we are getting like:

```
[ERROR] too many arguments for method complete: (m: => akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable)akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute
[ERROR]  complete(responseMessage.statusCode,  responseMessage.body )
```

After searching, the reason of this error is, our `HttpResponse` class, contains an abstract type, and while we put abstract type value to the `complete` method, it will not able to figure out what is the formatter for `CustomHttpResponse`. Even we were creating all formatter within in `CustomHttpResponse` companion objects. References for this are take from:

[akka http (un)marshall traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188419/akka-http-unmarshall) and
[JsonFormat for abstract class with generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969888/jsonformat-for-abstract-class-with-generic-parameter-traits)

I feels like, we are missing something. So, any one have idea what exactyle the problem is this? and what is the convenient way for handing these sinerios?

Answer (score 0):

**Indirect Solution**

I do not know the cause of the underlying problem related to the error message provided in the question.  However, I think there is a simpler solution to the overall problem you are trying to tackle.

The way that you are going about creating "custom" `HttpResponse` values is very object-oriented in nature.  I think that all of the custom hierarchy can be eliminated and replaced with the standard HttpResponse class from akka along with a functional approach.

You can write response manipulator functions that updated a response based on conditions:

```
val setStatus : HttpResponse => HttpResponse = 
  if(someCondition)
    (httpResponse) => httpResponse withStatus 200
  else
    (httpResponse) => httpResponse withStatus 500

val setHeaders : (Boolean) => HttpResponse => HttpResponse =
  (conditionProvided) => 
    if(conditionProvided)
      (httpResponse) => httpResponse withHeaders Seq(...)
    else
      (httpResponse) => httpResponse withHeaders Seq.empty[HttpHeader]

def defaultResponse : () => HttpResponse = HttpResponse()
```

These can then be used within a `Route` to create custom responses:

```
val route : Route = {
  val internalCondition : Boolean = ???

  val responsePipeline : () => HttpResponse = 
    defaultResponse andThen setStatus andThen setHeaders(internalCondition)

  complete(responsePipeline())
}
```